# Is it possible to use # stringization with defined constants?

Tags: c++, c

I've got some string constants where later ones are parly composed of earlier ones

```
const char* ID       = "01099BB2";
const char* FS_LOCATION_ROOT =  "fs:/~0x";
```

I want to create constants that are concatenations and tried using # as below but got compilation errors:

```
const char* FS_LOCATION = FS_LOCATION_ROOT#ID;
```

Is there a way of combining the strings in this way?

Comment: Stringification is a preprocessor feature. No such thing in the actual language C itself. If those are true constants, you could use preprocessor macros and #defines...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with those strings. The stringizer operand `#` is part of the preprocessor, and thus has to appear within a macro definition. It doesn't look like it would help you for your particular situation though. However, you could simply use the fact that secuential string literals get concatenated.

```
"fs:/~0x" "01099BB2" is turned into "fs:/~0x01099BB2"
```

However you cannot use that with variables, only with literals. You could do something like this:

```
#define ID "01099BB2"
#define FS_LOCATION_ROOT "fs:/~0x"

#define FS_LOCATION FS_LOCATION_ROOT ID
```

or better yet

```
const char* FS_LOCATION = FS_LOCATION_ROOT ID
```

However I would think it twice before defining a macro named `ID`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize they could get concatenated like that. The name ID is a truncated version for posting on here not the real name.

Answer (score 1):

Not once they are defined as symbols.  You could generate both at the same time, I suppose.

```
#define stupid_macro(ID,ROOT) \
  const char *id = #ID ; \
  const char *root = #ROOT ; \
  const char *both = #ID #ROOT ;
```

I didn't quite test it to verify the stringize stuff works, but it should end up with this.

```
const char *id = "id_val" ;
const char *root = "root_val" ;
const char *both = "id_val" "root_val" ;
```

The last of which will concatenated them.  This is certainly legal, though I can't say its moral.